# Перебор паролей на сайте

Tags: html, php

Добрый вечер ! 
Есть такая сложность или проблема....

1)Есть сайт , не важно какой сайт "Z" , где можно бесконечно раз вводить пароль , то есть перебирать пароль, и нужны способы достижения этой цели.

2)Тот же сайт "Z" , теперь задача наоборот нужно защита от перебора.
Я так подумал что после 3 неправильных , выскочит запрос с капчей или задачкой типа 2+2 = ? .

Но главным вопросом остается узнать какие виды есть реализации или более простые методы на задачу номер 1.

Comment: подставлять рандомные поля (в т.ч. и скрытые), при запросе проверять, какие данные введены. На задачу номер 1 - ищите bruteforce.

Comment: угу , и такая мысль была.
Я не знаю как может брут прямо на сайте работать, не понимаю как они работают.

Answer (score 3):

2 Навскидку:

- Блокирование по IP после ввода некоторого числа некорректных значений пароля(при грамотной реализации, помимо скриптов используется фервол, на подобии iptables).[обход с помощью socks]
- Блокирование по "кукам"(в том числе "не удаляемые" куки, да даже простые флеш куки)
- Блокирование по количеству попыток ввода неверного пароля, на время или по эвенту.
- Различные варианты реализации теста Тьюринга
- Комбинация перечисленных методов.

1 Выбрать сервер в той-же локальной сети, что и хост с сайтом, чтобы уменьшить время отклика. Варианты реализации брутфорса могут различаться, в зависимости от лимитов на мин и макс значение длины пароля, разрешенных символов в пароле, регистра букв, пропускной способности сети, отказоустойчивости/обработки ошибок доступа к странице сайта и т.д.

1а Использовать альтернативные методы получения доступа к сайту(хак, соц инженерию, трой).

Comment: Хакинг карается , хитрость и нетворкинг конечно были бы классно , вжиться в роль Митника )
Но хочется именно перебор , это в некоем роде как домашнее задание для самого себя )

Answer (score 1):

непонял в чем сложность 1 пункта?

по 2-ому, я бы сделал вот как: в таблице юзер добавил бы поля:
1 -которое отвечало бы за попытку входа. 
2- блок на вход.

Принцип. К примеру юзеру дается 3 попытки на вход без карательных мер, далее если 4 попытка неудлась - блокируем аккаунт например на 5 мин, если после жтого опять неудалась - блок на 20 мин и так далее. А когда юзер зашел - пофиг с какой попытки - то поле попыток входа сбрасываем.

Comment: Что то вроде паролей на айфоне получится , тоже идея, спасибо .
насчет первого , я никогда этого не делал , и для опыта хочу знать как это делается , как это юзается , инструменты. Понимаю что сейчас мало сайтов таких , без защиты от бесконечного ввода, но мне очень интересно .

Comment: Понимаю что сейчас мало сайтов таких - спорно) мне кажется наоборот )) просто с этим никто не заморачивается- средства защиты должны соразмерятся со стоимостью защищаемой информации.

Comment: Ну не посещаю такие сайты , но сама по себе задача как опыт очень интересная.